# Why i get an Error "Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (1)" using ipopt in pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

i tried to optimize a model with pyomo using ipopt. But everytime i try a model following error occurs:

"""
ERROR: Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: Solver log: Ipopt 3.5.5: Unknown keyword "max_cpu_time"
constr_viol_tol=1e-08
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Marvin Lang\Documents\Python Scripts\untitled0.py", line 21, in 
pe.SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(model, mip_solver='glpk', nlp_solver='ipopt')

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\MindtPy.py", line 113, in solve
return SolverFactory(_supported_algorithms[config.strategy][0]).solve(

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\algorithm_base_class.py", line 2800, in solve
self.MindtPy_initialization(config)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\algorithm_base_class.py", line 841, in MindtPy_initialization
self.init_rNLP(config)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\algorithm_base_class.py", line 877, in init_rNLP
results = nlpopt.solve(

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 627, in solve
raise ApplicationError("Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)

ApplicationError: Solver (ipopt) did not exit normally
"""

I also tried a code i found online:

import pyomo.environ as pe

model = pe.ConcreteModel()

model.x = pe.Var(bounds=(1.0,10.0),initialize=5.0)
model.y = pe.Var(within=pe.Binary)

model.c1 = pe.Constraint(expr=(model.x-4.0)**2 - model.x <= 50.0*(1-model.y))
model.c2 = pe.Constraint(expr=model.x*pe.log(model.x)+5.0 <= 50.0*(model.y))

model.objective = pe.Objective(expr=model.x, sense=pe.minimize)

pe.SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(model, mip_solver='glpk', nlp_solver='ipopt')

It would be nice if anybody have an idea about this problem.

I tried different versions of ipopt.
Version of Pyomo is 6.6.1

Comment: Are you setting additional solver options not shown in the code snippet you posted above? Does the code snippet you found online produce the same error? Ipopt 3.5.5 is a very old version from 2009. Have you tried updating your Ipopt install?

Answer (score 0):

max_cpu_time was introduced with Ipopt 3.6.0, so it is an unknown keyword for  Ipopt 3.5.5.
Update your Ipopt installation.